# Flip multiple vectors

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, network-analyst, direction

I have thousands of vectors (out of several million) which I need to flip, for directionally purposes (Network Analyst).

The vectors in question are annotated that their directionality has been reversed.

Anyone have or know of a way to flip multiple vectors at once or have any code which would do the same?

Comment: Do you mean transpose?

Comment: And are you using numpy? In numpy it is simply a.T, where a is some matrix. You can return this to a normal python list with tolist, or just a.T.tolist(). It would also be easy to write a double loop and just reverse the indexes for the transposed array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a [flipline tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001v00000005000000), though it doesn't seem to allow queries on a feature. it may be that you can provide the tool with a feature layer based on the selected attributes.

EDIT: As @JasonT mentioned, the flip tool should honor selections, so perhaps use [make feature layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Make_Feature_Layer/00170000006p000000/) with a SQL clause on the features that should be flipped and pass that layer to flipline.

from the link above:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace="C:/data"
inFeatures="harvestable.shp"
try:
    arcpy.FlipLine_edit(inFeatures)
except Exception, e:
     # If an error occurred, print line number and error message
    import traceback, sys
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    print "Line %i" % tb.tb_lineno
    print e.message
```

Comment: The flip tool honors selections or definition query, so just apply one or the other to the data 1st. (It will only flip those that are selected). If it is a large dataset, my favorite is the definition query, b/c it is faster.

Comment: John/Jason - Thank you.  I meant flipping a line vector (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m60000000r000000).  Jason I thin the flipline tool will work.  I believe I can modify that code for my needs - Thank you both